# Grails: ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed

Tags: spring, grails, hibernate-5.x

I want to set Hibernate5 plugin to my grails application, I use grails 3.1.1. I checked already this question and I followed it: [How to configure Grails 3.1.1 to use Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212787/how-to-configure-grails-3-1-1-to-use-hibernate-5)

However I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
Caused by:   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.CollectionType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/GrailsDomainBinder;)V
```

Comment: Same issue but only windows. Mac is working fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Windows using Grails 3.1.2

Comment: I have not updated yet. I am still on grails 3.0.10 :( I could not solve it

Comment: Seeing this now on tomcat 7 on Amazon Linux when I deploy. Currently using 3.1.3 grails to generate a WAR file.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much an error, rather Hibernate 5.1 is not (officially) supported in Grails yet - [issue #9783](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9783). No due date.

Comment: Thank you very much for the indication.

Comment: What about Hibernate 5.0, does anyone know if it will deploy to Jboss. I think I may be having the same problem, but my error message is slightly different.