# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-boot

I am  getting following exception while running Grails 3 application. I know that the version of hibernate which is `5.1.0.Final`do not have this class but I need to use this version. But the spring-boot is asking for this `Mappings` class. How to solve this?

```
    2016-03-13 00:48:09,355 30464 ERROR [main] [org.apache.commons.logging.Log$error$1] WARNING: You've configured a custom Hibernate naming strategy 'class org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy' in DataSource.groovy, however the class cannot be found.
Using Grails' default naming strategy: 'org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy'
2016-03-13 00:48:09,534 30643 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Mappings
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass$1.run(CachedSAMClass.java:104)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass$1.run(CachedSAMClass.java:102)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getDeclaredMethods(CachedSAMClass.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getAbstractMethods(CachedSAMClass.java:120)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethod(CachedSAMClass.java:186)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isSAM(ClassInfo.java:359)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.createCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:349)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.access$700(ClassInfo.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:488)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$4.initValue(CachedClass.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$4.initValue(CachedClass.java:138)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getCachedSuperClass(CachedClass.java:248)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$8.initValue(CachedClass.java:214)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$8.initValue(CachedClass.java:200)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getInterfaces(CachedClass.java:252)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.<init>(CachedClass.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.createCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:352)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.access$700(ClassInfo.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:488)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:180)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:216)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:228)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:171)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:161)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:253)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:75)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at grails.orm.bootstrap.HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer$_getBeanDefinitions_closure1.doCall(HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer.groovy:225)
        at grails.orm.bootstrap.HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer$_getBeanDefinitions_closure1.doCall(HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
        at grails.plugin.hibernate.HibernateGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure1.doCall(HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy:81)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:758)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:172)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:157)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:335)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:324)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.asklytics.mlaas.jmeter.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 99 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try removing the entry for custom Hibernate naming strategy class in DataSource.groovy

Comment: @SandeepPoonia custome Hibernate naming strategy is not defined anywhere. Also it is `Grails 3` so there is no `DataSource.groovy` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the hibernate from 4 to 5 in grails. see this link to update hibernate in grails [How to configure Grails 3.1.1 to use Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212787/how-to-configure-grails-3-1-1-to-use-hibernate-5)